# what is `get_section()` and how to use it?

Tags: functions, theme-development

i saw `get_section()` being used in WordPress. what is this function and how can i utilize it for theme development?

Comment: That code is not from WordPress. You'd need to ask the developer of whatever 'c27' is, whoever that is.

Comment: @JacobPeattie hello i know ..i just showed where `get_section`  is used

Comment: And? As I said, it's not a WordPress function. It's coming from whatever `c27()` is, which is also not from WordPress. Not that it's _not_ the `get_section()` from kero's answer. That was added before you included the code.

Comment: @JacobPeattie oh yes.  Thank you ..just noticed it is from a class.  i will update my question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you check the [code reference entry for `get_section()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wp_customize_manager/get_section/), you can see its description:

> Retrieve a customize section.

"customize" means the customizer, the theme handbook has a [complete chapter for using the customizer API](https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/customize-api/), and [one paragraph explaining sections](https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/customize-api/customizer-objects/#sections):

> Sections are UI containers for Customizer controls. While you can add custom controls to the core sections, if you have more than a few options you may want to add one or more custom sections. Use the [`add_section`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wp_customize_manager/add_section/) method of the [WP_Customize_Manager](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wp_customize_manager/) object to add a new section:

Comment: Thank you ..i was confused with usage..the dev has defined get_section inside a class so got confused with wordpress definition.. but in wordpress way it is  correct answer